# Next/Image show error "unable to verify the first certificate on next image" - NextJS

Tags: next.js, ssl-certificate, nextjs-image

so, basicly i fetched public api that have ssl error, and i fixed it with this line of variable.

```
Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    keepAlive: false,)}
```

but when i try to fetch image data with Next/Image it wont show up. I opened up the console it says Failed to load resource:

> the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

then i try to click the img url, its showing an error, it says

> FetchError: request to https://cdn01.site.com.... failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

and finally i use html img tag, and it perfectly fine.
Is there any possible ways to use Next/image for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by overriding the default loader

```
const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
 return `${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`
}
```

and

```
<Image
  loader={myLoader}
  src={imageUrl}
  alt="Picture of the author"
  width={500}
  height={500}
/>
```